# What is a permutation reordering?

Tags: permutations

What is a permutation reordering?

#### Example Problem

Input: A sequence of $n$ numbers: $a_1,a_2,\dotsc,a_n$.

Output: A permutation reordering $(a_1',a_2',\dotsc,a_n')$ of the input sequence such as $a_1'<a_2'<\dotsb<an'$.

In the above example and in general  what does permutation reordering mean?

Comment: I've never heard of a "permutation reordering". A permutation could be thought of as a sort of reordering, but this question seems a bit jumbled.